# Failed API test if run them in docker container

Tags: .net, docker, api, dockerfile

I have a problem if I run an api test in a container, it always crashes, if I don't use the container to run the test, then everything works.

I have an application that I'm testing through docker-compos. It is deployed locally and all api requests are sent to http://localhost:8080. If I understand correctly, then my container works with its internal localhost and therefore its requests are invalid.
There was an attempt to make a bridge but I did not understand how to do it at all.
I tried to add my image to the compose file, but it did not help

This is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /TAF.ReportPortal
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "te","--filter" ,"Category=DashboardApiTests", "--logger:trx", "--no-restore"]
```

This commands I use for starting container

```
docker build -t taf.rp:latest .
docker run --name taf.rp -p 8085:89 -d taf.rp
```

[Logs from my container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32vCr.png)

Comment: You seem to have attached an image file behind the link that says "logs".  Can you [edit] the question to include the logs directly in the question and in plain text?  The Dockerfile on its own probably isn't enough to reproduce the issue (what do the tests actually do?) and it also would help to make sure you've included a [mcve].